# Unable to query on date condition in specific range

Tags: java, jira, hsqldb, active-objects

I want to fetch the record from HSQL database and query is as below:

```
ao.find(Issueda.class, Query.select().where("user=? AND TO_DATE(START_TIME, 'yyyy/MM/dd')>=     TO_DATE(?,'yyyy/MM/dd') AND TO_DATE(END_TIME, 'yyyy/MM/dd') <= TO_DATE(?,'yyyy/MM/dd')",user,parsedDate,parsedDate))
```

Now, it gives me an error that "To_DATE" is not valid keyword as below:

```
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
 Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected token: TO_DATE in statement [SELECT * FROM    
PUBLIC.AO_0371A8_ISSUE_da WHERE user=? AND TO_DATE(START_TIME, 'yyyy/MM/dd')>= TO_DATE(?,'yyyy/MM/dd') AND    TO_DATE(END_TIME, 'yyyy/MM/dd') <= TO_DATE(?,'yyyy/MM/dd')]
```

If i remove "To_date" then i am not getting correct result data from data and return null only even though data are existed in database.
In database date field value's format is "2013-05-15 00:00:00.000000000"

Can any one plz share me any alternative to query to database ??

Comment: There is no need to use to_date on start_date and end_date if they are already in date format . Try this `ao.find(Issueda.class, Query.select().where("user=? AND START_TIME>= TO_DATE(?,'yyyy/MM/dd') AND END_TIME<= TO_DATE(?,'yyyy/MM/dd')",user,parsedDate,parsedDate))`

Comment: @SantoshPingale I just tried: it gives me error as - at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected token: TO_DATE in statement [SELECT * FROM PUBLIC.AO_0371A8_ISSUE_da WHERE user=? AND START_TIME >= TO_DATE(?,'yyyy/MM/dd') AND END_TIME <= TO_DATE(?,'yyyy/MM/dd')]

Comment: You don't need TO_DATE for this query. Use `START_TIME > ? AND END_TIME < ?` then create a java.sql.Data to set the PreparedStatement variable. TO_DATE is for converting dates that are in String format.

Comment: @fredt i have removed to_date , now that error is removed for to_date. But i am not getting any result even though records are existed in database. My condition is as follow : "START_TIME >= ? AND END_TIME <= ?"  In database records are existed as - "END DATE - 2013-05-24 00:00:00.000000000" , "START DATE - 2013-05-20 00:00:00.000000000" and the parameter value is '2013-05-20' (after cast to sql). But it does not return any records. Do i need to add milisecond also..?

Comment: @fredt I have changed the condition as follow - "START_TIME = ? OR END_TIME = ? OR (START_TIME < ? AND END_TIME > ?) Now, this is work for match condition as - 'START_TIME = ?" but it does not work when date is between start and end time  (i.e. START_TIME < ? AND END_TIME > ?) and unable to get those result... any idea, do i have to cast the date or any cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need TO_DATE for this query. TO_DATE is for converting dates that are in String format.

It seems from your comments you want one parameter to be between the two dates, or outside the two dates.

The correct SQL for this type of query is like this:

This returns dates between start and end, inclusive:

```
WHERE USER=? AND ? BETWEEN CAST(START_TIME AS DATE) AND CAST(END_TIME AS DATE)
```

This returns dates outside start and end:

```
WHERE USER=? AND ? NOT BETWEEN CAST(START_TIME AS DATE) AND CAST(END_TIME AS DATE)
```

For the above queries, you use a java.sql.Data object with `PreparedStatement.setDate(colIndex)`

Now if the date you want to compare is a String in a format such as '2013/05/20' then you need `TO_DATE(?,'yyyy/MM/dd')` instead of the parameter. If the date is a String in standard format such as '2013-05-20' then you can use `CAST(? AS DATE)` instead of the parameter.

I assume your database table columns START_TIME and END_TIME are defined as of TIMESTAMP type, but it should work for VARCHAR(N) or CHAR(N) types.

Comment: Excellent @fredt . It works for me. your first query is actually resolve the things "dates between start and end, inclusive:". Many Thanks !.